# Does dropdown navigational menu in smaller screen crawlable by search bots?

Tags: seo, search-engines

I am confused as a colleague of mine who is a SEO expert told me that navigational links such as (home, about, contact, etc.) inside dropdown menu (using bootstrap css) is not crawlable? Is this true? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say 9/10 times, Google can view links contained within dropdown menus. Most of the menus I have seen are technically lists and are styled with CSS. So the underlying code is still a list and would be immediately seen by Google upon crawl.

The only issue would be if the site is generating the menu contents dynamically. This would mean the dropdown isn't technically populated until it is expanded, then the site - with the help of JavaScript - is populating the contents. Those would probably not be crawlable.

An easy way to check (although it isn't 100% foolproof) is to inspect the page's code. If upon load, the links are there even with the menus in their normal state (not expanded), then they are crawlable. If not, Google might not be able to see them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.